# odata : how to use tolower in startswith

Tags: odata, startswith, tolower

When I use odata like this: $filter=startswith(tolower(firstName),tolower('A'))
it doesn't work.

I want to know that whether tolower or toupper can work with startswith?

Answer (score 6):

That should work.

As an example on a live service, try this:

```
http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=startswith(tolower(Name),'b')
```

In that service, there is a Product that has the Name "Bread". If you don't include the `tolower` call in the URL, you won't get this entity returned. If you do include `tolower`, the "Bread" product will be included.